# Is there a formula that finds a previous value in a column list?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Looking for a formula that will find previous value in a column list and read its corresponding code next to it. If there is no previous value then it should show nothing. So for instance I have a long list similar to below( which BTW will constantly grow adding more names with values!! ):
[image]

The pool of names will always be the same but the code will always change I will have a dropdown list (In cell H4) with all the names and depending on which name is chosen from the dropdown I would like to have a previous value (say in cell H5). So in the example above if Sue is chosen the value 796 would be correct value showing in H5. If Adam is chosen then value 045 if Andy is chosen there should be no value as there is no previous value for Andy etc. Is there a formula that would handle this. I was trying to use vlookup however it always brings last value. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for `VLOOKUP`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `H5`, enter formula :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B3:B10,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(A3:A10)-ROW(A2)/(A3:A10=H4),2)),"")
```

Comment: thank you  it worked brilliantly one question though. I did mention that the column A will constant be growing adding names ( the pool of names will stay the same) would this have any impact on the formula? I guess What I am asking is there a way to add something similar to xlDown in VBA only on  formula level to mark last entry in the column A. An offset perhaps ?

Comment: For a growing list, you can use "Excel Table", the formula range will change to Table name and will auto adjust in respect of  the data list growing. Further details please Google "Excel Table".

Answer (score -1):

=INDEX(A:B,MATCH(D6,A:A,0)-1,2)

-1 in the row sets it one higher.
This assumes that all names are in column A and all numbers are in column B.

Comment: When I try this I get the result of the person the line before the first result of the selected person. In the example above, if I enter "Sue" I get result 045 (from B3)